# readom and dd are creating different ISO-Images

Tags: linux, iso-image, dd

When I am making an ISO-Image from a disc, according to the MD5-Hash of the created file, there is a difference between the data. They also differ in size. Tested on two completely different devices.

```
470b6924c8ac02975f816e4bbae019e2  test_dd.iso
470b6924c8ac02975f816e4bbae019e2  test_original.iso
a26665962c1afc4cf73de261959ba33f  test_readom.iso
470b6924c8ac02975f816e4bbae019e2  test_brasero_iso9660.iso
00d73e6b29230b41429357945df529ba  test_brasero_readom.iso


-rw-r--r-- 1 614400 Jan  6 12:02 test_dd.iso
-rw-r--r-- 1 614400 Jan  6 11:53 test_original.iso
-rw-r--r-- 1 524288 Jan  6 12:02 test_readom.iso
```

Both dd and readom report an input/output error:

"dd if=/dev/cdrom of=test_dd.iso" output:

```
dd: error reading ‘/dev/cdrom’: Input/output error
1200+0 records in
1200+0 records out
614400 bytes (614 kB) copied, 5.00922 s, 123 kB/s
```

"readom dev=/dev/cdrom f=test_readom.iso" output:

```
Read  speed:  4234 kB/s (CD  24x, DVD  3x).
Write speed:  2822 kB/s (CD  16x, DVD  2x).
Capacity: 302 Blocks = 604 kBytes = 0 MBytes = 0 prMB
Sectorsize: 2048 Bytes
Copy from SCSI (1,0,0) disk to file 'test_readom.iso'
end:       302
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), read_g1 scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  28 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 2E 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: F0 00 05 00 00 01 2D 0A 00 00 00 00 64 00 00 00
Sense Key: 0x5 Illegal Request, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x64 Qual 0x00 (illegal mode for this track) Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 301 (valid) 
cmd finished after 0.495s timeout 40s
readom: Input/output error. Cannot read source disk
readom: Retrying from sector 256.
    ..............................................~~-~~~+~~~-~~~+~~~-~~~+~~~-~~~+~~~-~~~+~~~-~~~+~~~-~~~+~~~-~~~+~~~-~~~+~~~-~~~+~~~-~~~+~~~-~~~+~~~-~~~+~~~-~~~+~~~-~~~
readom: Input/output error. Error on sector 301 not corrected. Total of 1 errors.

Time total: 38.983sec
Read 512.00 kB at 13.1 kB/sec.
Max corected retry count was 0 (limited to 128).
The following 1 sector(s) could not be read correctly:
301
```

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/311365/16920

Answer (score 0):

`dd` is unstable in Debian/Ubuntu because it does not have any built-in error checking. 
Your `dd` error is not related to your `readom` error. 
The latter error is in much later stage.

However, your `readom` shows that there is one error which seems to be related to my issue in the thread [How to copy CDROM with readom in Debian 8.x?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/311365/16920) 
I also added comments in the documentation of the used commands in Commandlinefu.